# How do I access a structure using an object of a class through a different pointer?(LINKED LISTS)(C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list, structure

My program crashes when I try to call a member of struct using a pointer that points to the same memory block. Forgive me for the bad code I've only recently gotten into c++(it's been about 2 months).

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
struct node 
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
class trial
{
    node *hello;
public:
    trial()
    {
        hello=new node;
        hello->data=0;
        hello->next=NULL;
    }
    friend void access(trial);
    void get();
};
void access(trial t1)
{
    node *temp;
    temp=t1.hello;
//My program stops working after I write the following line of code:
    cout<<temp->data;

}
int main()
{
    trial t1;
    access(t1);
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot a `->next`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `access()`, you are passing in the `t1` parameter **by value**, which means the compiler is going to make a **copy** of the input object. But your `trial` class does not support proper copy semantics (see the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)), so the `t1` parameter is not initialized correctly.

You should pass the `t1` parameter **by reference** instead to avoid the copy:

```
void access(trial &t1)
```

Preferably by `const` reference instead, since `access()` doesn't modify `t1`:

```
void access(const trial &t1)
```